# how to migrate from .NET1.1 to .NET3.5 version

Tags: asp.net

currently iam using .NET1.1 version in next few days i will be migrating this .NET1.1 application to .NET3.5 version...so my question is how to migrate this .NET1.1 to .NET3.5..?
How to migrate this & what precuations i need to take...? plz help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio for your development there is an upgrade feature that takes care of quite a few things.

Here is an article on the topci that might help you. [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pandrew/archive/2007/10/25/how-to-upgrade-from-net-framework-1-0-to-net-framework-3-5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @Development4.0 suggested, you could open the 1.1 sln file in VS2008 and go through the wizards. If you have multiple projects (like Web Projects, Class Library etc), then I would suggest a step-by-step approach. There will be breaking changes for sure, but I think would be minimal.